# MYSQL Join table rows and use for php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have multiple tables on specific database and each table similar to each other.

**Table:**

```
 id     series     folder
  1      Naruto     670
  2      Naruto     671
  3      Naruto     672
```

Each table has exact setup. Just series name changes. I want to pick up only 1 entry from series row and highest number from the folder row.
I will use this data to make it php array and use it for JSON data. 
Here is my code:

```
'SELECT naruto.MAX(klasor), naruto.seri, one_piece.MAX(klasor), one_piece.seri, bleach.MAX(klasor), bleach.seri FROM `naruto` INNER JOIN `one_piece` INNER JOIN `bleach ON` LIMIT 1'
```

Comment: what happens when you have a typo and Naruto is supposed to be Narutu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `GROUP BY` clause like

```
select id,series,max(folder) as max_folder
from table1
group by series
```